# How do you set DateTime range on X axis for System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Presently I am attempting to display a chart using windows forms that shows monthly data on the X axis and an integer value on the Y axis; however, I am not setting the range properly for the X Axis, where MonthYear is a DateTime:

```
var pnChart = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
pnChart.Controls.Clear();
DataTable dtChartData = myDatabaseLayer.BuildDataTable("SELECT Added, Modified FROM tblStatistics WHERE ApplicationID = " + intApplicationID + " ORDER BY MonthYear");
Chart chart = GenerateChart(dtChartData, pnChart.Width, pnChart.Height, "ActiveBorder", 6);
chart.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
pnChart.Controls.Add(chart);
```

The problem is, when the chart is displayed, the X axis has the datetime "1900-01-01" so my question is, how do I set the date range to start at 2013-01-01?

Please note that I have searched the internet and tried the following settings, but they do not give me the correct range:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Or,

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Or,

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

TIA.

**UPDATE:**
Please note that I found how to set the range properly using this:

```
            chart.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);
            DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Now;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
```

The above code sets the proper range now for the X axis; however, now chart itself is blank.

**UPDATE 2:**

Yes, thank you DasKrumelmonster--that fixed it!  I was using code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168056/Windows-Charting-Application, and simply should have looked more closely at the author's protected internal Chart GenerateChart(DataTable dtChartDataSource, int width, int height, string bgColor, int intType) function.  To correct the issue, I changed these lines:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtChartDataSource.Rows)
{
    double dataPoint = 0;
    double.TryParse(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), out dataPoint);
    DataPoint objDataPoint = new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "series", YValues = new double[] { dataPoint } };
     chart.Series[series].Points.Add(dataPoint);
}
```

To this:

```
DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);
int intMonthCounter = 0;
//Add data points to the series
foreach (DataRow dr in dtChartDataSource.Rows)
{
    double dataPoint = 0;
    double.TryParse(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), out dataPoint);
    DataPoint objDataPoint = new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "series", YValues = new double[] { dataPoint } };
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(dtStart.AddMonths(intMonthCounter),  dataPoint);
    intMonthCounter++;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Cannot reproduce. I tried this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = new Series();
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    var d = new DateTime(2013, 04, 01);

    s.Points.AddXY(d, 3);
    s.Points.AddXY(d.AddMonths(-1), 2);
    s.Points.AddXY(d.AddMonths(-2), 1);
    s.Points.AddXY(d.AddMonths(-3), 4);

    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add(s);


    chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea()); // In some cases the winforms designer adds this already
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;

    chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01).AddSeconds(-1);
    DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(2013, 05, 01); // or DateTime.Now;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
}
```

Maybe I fixed your error on the way.

It works as expected: One line with four data points, all x-axes labels are visible and so is the graph itself. If there is still an issue, please provide full testing code along with a description of what should happen vs. what actually happens.

Comment: Copied this for testing. No result showing up. The chart-area is just empty.

Comment: Interesting. I just tried it again, and it works for me. 1) Create a new WindowsForms project. 2. Drop a button and a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart on the form 3) double click the button to create the event handler 4) insert the code from above 5) run & enjoy. You may want to adjust the max-limit.

Comment: Hah. Just the way I tried. Looks like its a specific problem for me as it worked for the thread creator. Anyway, I upvoted this. Some parts were really helpful. Got a working code now.