# ASP.NET Chart control set month names from int value on X Axis labels

Tags: asp.net, formatting, mschart, axis-labels

I want to replace numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) on the X Axis of the chart with the corresponding month name.

This is my actual chart:

[image: Actual chart]

On the `DataView` that populates the `Series` I have the "MONTH" column that contains values from 1 to 12.
I also had to manually set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` value to 0 and 13, otherwise I lose the first and last column because of a lack of space between the beginning of the first X Axis column and the Y Axis and between the last X Axis column end of Chart area.

```
<ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        <AxisX IsStartedFromZero="True" Title="Mese"
            TitleFont="Segoe UI, 10pt, style=Bold" IsLabelAutoFit="False" LineColor="Gray"
            Minimum="0" Maximum="13">
            <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
            <LabelStyle Font="Segoe UI, 9pt" />
        </AxisX>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```

So, if I replace the int values with month names I also need to remove the Min and Max parameters, but I want to keep the space like it is now.

I tried with some solutions suggested here and elsewhere but with no results.
The easiest, most effective and immediate seemed to be this:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM";
```

but it doesn't work. Instead I get "MMM" string in place of the integer values.

Is it possible to intercept the `DataBind` event like on a GridView, to replace the integer values with month names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to use custom labels.
I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6679985/1974021) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218957/1974021).

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebTest_1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 83);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 63);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 53);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(4, 77);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(5, 46);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(6, 99);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(7, 72);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(8, 39);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(9, 42);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(10, 71);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(11, 58);
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(12, 63);

            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(1 , 46);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(2 , 72);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(3 , 53);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(4 , 39);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(5 , 63);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(6 , 71);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(7 , 75);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(8 , 99);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(9 , 83);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(10, 63);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(11, 58);
            Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(12, 42);
        }

        protected void Chart1_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var lbl in Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels)
            {
                int monthNumber = int.Parse(lbl.Text);
                if (monthNumber >= 1 && monthNumber <= 12)
                    lbl.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthNumber);
                else
                    lbl.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

You need to assign the Customize event.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
Anyway I thought it was someway possible to use the `Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` property that would have been a more elegant solution.

Comment: That would probably work, if you had actual DateTime values ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15907556/1974021))

Comment: I give a try to the other solution and updated this question with new results. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Your int values are _not_ converted to month names. Your axis displays fine, but it represents 2013-01-01 until 31-12-2013 (in OAdates) and not generic months. That means it has values between 41275 and 41639. Your data is between 1 and 12, so it will not show up.

Comment: Ok. Definitely no way... I'll stay on the `Customize` event solution! Thanks!

Comment: This should be accepted answer in ALL the questions for MSGraph axis formatting. Finally found it.