# Misplaced year label on mschart axis

Tags: c#, charts, label, mschart

I have a chart where the x-axis is composed of dates, with yearly intervals. The problem is, depending on the minimum date, the minimum label is or is not shown. Check below:

```
var s = new Series();
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

var d = new DateTime(2013, 04, 01);

s.Points.AddXY(d.AddYears(-1), 3);
s.Points.AddXY(d, 3);
s.Points.AddXY(d.AddYears(1), 2);
s.Points.AddXY(d.AddYears(2), 1);
s.Points.AddXY(d.AddYears(3), 4);

chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.Series.Add(s);


chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 2;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;


chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01);
DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 01);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
```

When running the code above, the minimum date has no label (the first label is 2012), however, if you use 2012 as the minimum year, it will be shown. This only happens on a higher than 1 interval, and becomes worse the greater the value. I have no idea as to why this happens. I have also tried setting the interval properties (minus offset) for the LabelStyle, but to no avail.

[image: This image shows what happens]

PS: Sample code extracted form [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907556/how-do-you-set-datetime-range-on-x-axis-for-system-windows-forms-datavisualizati), with some modifications
Tested on .NET 4.5.1 and 3.5

Comment: Maybe there is not quite enough room? Can you choose a tighter or smaller  Font?

Comment: If the font is the problem, why would it show when using a different year? Surely there is no significant differente between "2012" and "2011" in font size? Also if the labels get cramped up it automatically gets organized, i believe its called 'smartlabel'

Comment: Actually there is. But the reason could also be how the labels are being spread along the axis.. Can you post one or two images?

Comment: Done. Check it out. I find hard to believe that the font is the issue here. Do you still think so?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm [blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251064/possble-imgur-block-by-german-isp-1und1) from seeing the images. Maybe somebody else will jump in. Hopefully the block will go away soon..

Comment: I'm playing with your code, and you are right, it is certainly not the Font!

Comment: Would this be what you want: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = -1;` ? (Besides understanding the rules ;-)

Comment: Albeit that would work on this example (although it would break when using 2012), in my real world application i do not know the minimum year, and since there is no apparent logic to this behavior, i cannot apply this workaround.

Comment: I have found the logic behind it. The first label to be shown is the one higher or equal to the minvalue which is a multiple of the interval. So, for an interval of 3: [2011,2012] ->2013; [2014,2015]->2016. This way the offset can be dynamically calculated.

Comment: Sounds right. Do put it in the question as an update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first label to be shown is the one higher or equal to the minvalue which is a multiple of the interval. So, for an interval of 3: [2011,2012] ->2013; [2014,2015]->2016. This way the offset can be dynamically calculated with some simple math.

```
var offset = -(interval - (minYear % interval));
```

Although the problem is solved, it still makes no sense to me. Why do this on a date axis and not a numerical one? Sounds more like a bug.